# ASP classic chat applet with logging

Tags: asp-classic

I've got a crappy legacy chat script running in an iFrame on a page. It shows the logged-in user and logs all the chat back and forth. Simple messaging only.

What options are there for something I can run without an iFrame within a page?

Comment: Well, AJAX comes to mind, but I'm not sure if that's specifically what you are asking. Do you want to get rid of the iframe for some reason, or the entire script?

Answer (score 0):

U can easily do it with Ajax (via jquery) ... here is a good example http://tutorialpot.com/2011/07/ajax-and-jquery-chat-system/